# Listview blocks gestures

Tags: android

```
public class Main extends Activity {
GestureDetectorCompat gdc;
ListView list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    gdc = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GesturesClass());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gdc.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}


class GesturesClass extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        //Bring left activity
        if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > 100){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Finished.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Bring left actitivty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if((Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX())) > 100){
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Bring right actitivty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Unfinished.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

Okay so I have implemented gestures which include fling to left and right to start new activity on each side. Everything should work perfectly. When I set list view items, listview starts blocking my gestures. I did a search about dispatchTouchEvent which gives you priority of touch event by I could not understand how to implement it in my case. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it should be something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gdc.onTouchEvent(event)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

add a custom `onTouchListener` for the `ListView`, and let it `return gdc.onTouchEvent(event);`

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gdc.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works the way I implmented. Although the listview still blocks gestures.

Comment: then you should add a custom onTouchListener for the ListView, and if `return  gdc.onTouchEvent(event);`